# Как закрепить горизонтальный скрол для таблицы к нижней части сайта

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как закрепить горизонтальный скрол для таблицы к нижней части сайта, чтобы скролбар был всегда на виду(зафиксирован в нижней части экрана)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>

  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
html,body,.container, .table-responsive, .table {
  height: 100%;
}

.table-responsive{
 overflow: hidden;
}

thead, tbody { display: block; }

thead {
    height: 50px;
    overflow-y: auto; 
}
tbody {
    height: 85%;
    overflow-y: auto; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>

  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```